# Linux Shell - How to copy directory without symlink

Tags: files, copy, symlink, cp

I would like to get everything inside one directory.

How can I copy entire directory (that originally contains files and symlinks) to a new directory that should contains all files but no symlink??

Thank you

Comment: do a small bash script

Comment: lol, this is not the question

Answer (score 3):

Run this command

```
find (Old dir) -depth -type f -o -type d | cpio -pamVd /New/Directory
```

it will only copy files and directories, but not symlinks

Example:

```
find . -depth -type f -o -type d | cpio -pamVd /root/mydir
```

this will recursively copy all the file/directories from current directory to /root/mydir

Comment: does OP want symlinks converted into files or just ignored?

Comment: not sure about that

Answer (score 1):

Or simply copy everything, then delete the symlinks.

```
cp -R /path/source /path/dest; find /path/dest -type l -exec rm -f {} \;
```